# allow user in forms authentication wont work in azure website

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, forms-authentication, azure-web-app-service

I have a website on Azure - example.azurewebsites.net.
I configured the default page to index.html.
Now, the website suppose to deny unauthenticated users to website, except index.html and login.html.

That's my code:

```
   <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="index.html" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
    <location path="index.html">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms loginUrl="login.html" defaultUrl="~/" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
         <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
```

example.azurewebsites.net/index.html - this works.
example.azurewebsites.net - and this does not (redirects to login.html).
But they supposed to be the same.
Without authentication example.azurewebsites.net redirects to index.html no problem.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you may wish to check is if the following exists on your web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
  <add name="FormsAuthenticationModule" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" />
</modules>
```

You don't usually need to do this as the module is defined in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config on your local OS. It however, is not the case on Azure Web Service environment.

Comment: It works for me!!! After many wasted hours searching for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I configured the default page to index.html. Now, the website suppose to deny unauthenticated users to website, except index.html and login.html.

If you’d like to restrict user access to web pages in your application with forms authentication, please refer to the following Web.config.

```
<location path="index.html">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>

<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    <buildProviders>
      <add extension=".html" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
    </buildProviders>
  </compilation>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>

   <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="login.html" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH">
    </forms>
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
   <handlers>
    <add name="HTML" path="*.html" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG"   type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

> example.azurewebsites.net/index.html - this works. example.azurewebsites.net - and this does not (redirects to login.html). But they supposed to be the same.

Please make sure if you specify index.html  as [default document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-configure).

Edit:

> example.azurewebsites.net - and this does not (redirects to login.html).

We could create a URL Rewrite rule to redirect user from example.azurewebsites.net to example.azurewebsites.net/index.html.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="redirecttoindexpage" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="/index.html" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks. index.html is indeed specified as default document. Actually, when I remove the forms authentication example.azurewebsites.net redirects to index.html no problem. The problem is only with forms authentication.